# How do I customize ckeditor's toolbar

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and want to customize the toolbar and text entering area as the gap between  two sentences much.
I am unable to find the toolbar.js or config.js where i should do the changes..

how do i customize the above both

Comment: Did you check the [ckeditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/)? Can you provide an image of what you have and what you want it to be?

Comment: You should take a look on the CKEditor page instead, see http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide

Answer (score 40):

Sonal's answer isn't wrong in itself, but **DOESN'T REFER TO CKEDITOR.**  **FCKeditor** was (and is) a good product, but it's now replaced by the new CKEditor, so using those config might not really work.

As you can read in the docs [**here**](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations#Using_the_config.js_File), you can pass custom configuration options by editing the `config.js` file, which is located in the root folder of CKeditor (in a fresh installation..if you moved it act accordingly)

The file already contains these lines:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
        // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};
```

You can the find the WHOLE list of available configuration in their [**API DOCS**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html). Coming to your problem, you can set what you want/don't want in your toolbars like this (check the [toolbar](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar) §):

```
// This is actually the default value.
config.toolbar_Full =
[
    { name: 'document',    items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms',       items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links',       items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles',      items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools',       items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
];
```

As for the lines being to high, I don't know if you want to change at rendering mode or if you want to change the default behaviour of isnerting a `<p>` tag at each line break.
In the latter case, use

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

You can find a detailed explanation [here (EnterMode §)](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode)

If you want, you can also pass **custom configs** at runtime by using:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( '#textarea_id', { customConfig : '/myconfig.js' } );
```

Or this (to replace your custom with the fall-back of the default ones)

```
CKEDITOR.replace( '#textarea_id', { customConfig : '' } );
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful and solves your issues, please considering upvoting it and/or marking as accepted, for future references. And if you still have problems, just ask :) Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        CKEDITOR.replace(
            'textarea_name',
            {
                toolbar: [
                    ['Image','Flash']
                ],
            },
            {height: 550},{width:500}
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most easy example

```
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id', {
    toolbar: [
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'TextColor', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']
    ],
    height: 100,
    skin: 'v2',
    enterMode: 1,
    shiftEnterMode: 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**its Working for me**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('article', {
    toolbar: [
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'TextColor', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']
    ]
});
```

[image]