# CKEditor: Change value from config.js at runtime?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, config

I would like to have a switch for CKEditor's feature "[forcePasteAsPlainText](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forcePasteAsPlainText)" that you can enable in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
}
```

From my website's js-file I now try to change the value for forcePasteAsPlainText with jquery:

```
 if(typeof(CKEDITOR) !== 'undefined') { 
    $('#filterTextButton').click(function () {
        CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = !CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText;
        if(CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText) {
            $("#filterSwitch").html("OFF");
        }
        else {
            $("#filterSwitch").html("ON");
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that I cannot access **CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText**. I get an undefined.

Converting the object *CKEDITOR.config* to a string, I see that there is an object named *CKEDITOR.config.plugins* holding a parameter called "pastetext" (belonging to forcePasteAsPlainText). But I don't know how to read or set this anew.

I read that one possibility to change the config value is to reinitialize the entire editor by [replacing it at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078586/1066234)... but there must be another solution!?

PS: I [read here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16466&start=0) that you could use the following but this did not work for me:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
   ev.editor._.commands.paste = ev.editor._.commands.pastetext;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to modify `forcePasteAsPlaintext` without reinitializing editor. You can check here http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/pastetext/plugin.js#L56 that this config setting is used only once - at startup.

Alternative solution is to switch off/on forcing paste as plaintext manually. E.g. like this:

```
// Set to false to switch forcing off.
var force = true;

editor.on( 'beforeCommandExec', function ( evt )
{
     var mode = evt.data.commandData;
     if ( force && evt.data.name == 'paste' && mode != 'html' )
     {
         editor.execCommand( 'pastetext' );
         evt.cancel();
     }
}, null, null, 0 );

editor.on( 'beforePaste', function( evt )
{
    if ( force )
        evt.data.mode = 'text';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have used a workaround now where I remove html tags from pasted data: http://codesel.blogspot.com/2012/08/ckeditor-remove-html-tags-from-pasted.html